# Complicated Star Pattern?

Tags: php, web-applications, for-loop

Okay, so I have a unique problem that I ran into when trying to code a 5x3 star pattern. I can do the for loops to get the 5x3, that's easy. However I need something different than a square.

We can have a maximum of 15 stars. So printing out a full block would look like this:

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

But we can pass in a parameter for the number of stars that we want. So let's pass in 11 instead of 15. We should get:

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
* *
```

However, with 11 as my parameter the output is like this:

```
* 
* *
* *
*
```

It prints out the correct number of rows with the incorrect number of stars. I know why this is, and it's because of the modulus in my code. I also tried a different approach, which printed out one less row than needed. I am stuck and not sure where to go from here.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    $num = 11;
    $rows = ceil($num/3);
    $count - 0;
    for($j = 0; $j < $rows; $j++){
        echo '<div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails">';
        for($i = $num%3; $i < 3; $i++){
            echo '*';
            $count++;
        }
        $num-=$count;
        echo '</ul></div>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Seems like you could use an actual `table` for this.

Comment: I didn't think about that before, one answer below uses tables for a solution which is really nice.

Comment: Of course you could use tables, but it depends of WHAT you're representing. In my opinion tables should only resperent data/facts of some sort.

Comment: What I will be representing is a gallery of videos with descriptions, basically.

Answer (score 0):

With some simple PHP-Fu:

```
$stars = 11;
$row_length = 3;


$array = array_fill(0, $stars, '*');
$array = array_chunk($array, $row_length);

$table = '<table border="0">';
foreach($array as $row){
    $table .= '<tr><td>'. implode('</td><td>', $row) .'</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hFX4En).

Comment: Thank you this works. I never thought about using a table for this, which makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do.

Comment: @JuPow Well the table is just something extra, I hope you got the idea of using array_fill() and array_chunk() :)

Comment: does the array_chunk() just take sub arrays of 3 from the main array?

Comment: Hmmm, well it "splits" the array in pieces of "3", the last one may not contain 3, but that's what we wanted. Furthermore, you can use `$row_length` to make a table 5 width for example. To take a more in depth understanding, just add `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';` after the code, you will see the "structure" of array !

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, this is what you need.

```
$num = 11;
$cols = 3;
$rows = ceil($num/$cols);

for($j=0;$j<$rows;$j++)
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    for($i=0;$i<$cols;$i++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

To show where you went wrong in your code. First, your definition of $count should be `=` not `-`. Next, your inner `for` loop is odd.

First loop through, `$num` is equal to `11`. In your inner loop you set `$i = $num%3` which is `$i = 2`. So the inner loop runs through once while `$i++ < 3`, echo's one star and increments count once. inner loop exits, you subtract `$count` from `$num` making `$num=10` and row is completed, next outer loop iteration.

Next time the inner loop runs, `$num` is 10 so `$i = $num%3` becomes `$i=1`. Inner loop runs 2 times while `$i++ < 3`, echo'ing 2 more stars and incrementing $count both times making it now 3. after the inner loop you subtract 3 more from `$num` making it 7 and row ends, outer loop continues.

Next inner loop, `$num` is 7 so `$i = $num%3` becomes `$i=1`. Inner loop runs 2 times while `$i++ < 3`, echo'ing 2 more stars and incrementing $count both times making it now 5. after the inner loop you subtract 5 from `$num` making it now 2, row ends, outer loop continues.

Last iteration of the outer loop (row limit hit), `$num` is 2 so `$i = $num%3` becomes `$i=1`. Inner loop runs once, echo's one star and inrement count once making it now 8. Inner loop finishes, you subtract 8 from `$num` making it now -6, row ends, outer loop ends.

Comment: This still prints out 3 stars for each row.

Comment: Yeah, when I went through the iterations of this I realized my for loops were way wrong haha.

Answer (score 0):

The idea should be as simple as: keep drawing until you reach the target number.

So you could do this:

```
$num = 11;
for( $i=0; $i<$num; $i+=3) {
    echo "<div class=\"row-fluid\"><ul class=\"thumbnails\">";
    for( $j=0; $j<3 && $i+$j<$num; $j++) {
        echo "*";
    }
    for( ; $j<3; $j++) { // finish the current row (optional, remove if not needed)
        echo " ";
    }
    echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Comment: This also works well, thanks. I just have been racking my brain on this problem for a while and got stuck haha.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh a puzzle!

I don't know if using `for` was a requirement for your assignment, I prefer `while`.

```
 $num_of_stars = 15;
 $stars_per_row = 3;
 while($num_of_stars > 0){
    echo "*";
    if($stars_per_row == 1){
        $stars_per_row = 3;
        echo "<br />";
    }else{
        $stars_per_row --;
    }
    $num_of_stars --;
 }
```

Comment: It wasn't a requirement actually I just thought that would be the best approach to do this. This assignment is a team project where we build a web application. It's really fun! Also, the stars won't actually be stars, I just needed to represent what I am doing in a simple way.

Comment: I prefer simplicity as well. That's why I stuck with just the single loop in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would have to use two for-loops.

I would do something like this: (I noticed you don't have any `<li>`'s in your code) Of course you would have to set the class="thumbnails" to include list-style-type:none;

```
<?php
    $num = 11;
    $cols = 3;

    echo '<div class="row-fluid"><ul class="thumbnails">';
    $count = 0;
    for($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++){
        $count++;

        echo '<li style="float:left;">*</li>';
        if ($count>=$cols) {
            $count = 0;
            echo '<li style="clear:both;"></li>';
        }

     }
     echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Comment: The stars aren't actually what I am using, I just asked with stars to make it more simple. That's why there are missing `<li>`s. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :-) btw, I didn't the stars was the actual issue :-)